# How correct the import error of libpng15 for cv2?[resolve]

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I'm trying to install opencv to use yolov4 but I have encountered an issue when I try to import cv2 on python:

```
ImportError: libpng15-c2ffaf3d.so.15.13.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed opencv with:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv
```

and I try:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

but it didn't help.

I have found nothing on `libpng15-c2ffaf3d` on the internet so if someone can help it will save me.

Comment: Any solution? I'm having this same error while trying to copy cv .so into a venv /site-packages

Comment: I had the same error while building opencv from source in virtual env, in my case build files were stored in a folder named "local" (i.e package was located at different path) i manually copied  the "bin","include","share","lib" from local folder to my venv it worked..!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the package is not located where python is searching,You can try

Solution:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my Linux environment of pythonanywhere.
I created the virtual environment and installed my package of open-cv
using:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

But it was raising this exception:

```
ImportError at /: libpng15-c2ffaf3d.so.15.13.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I installed another package using:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

which resolved my issue.

Make sure you install it in the same virtual environment.